# Image Processing YCbCr images

Tags: matlab

I am working on image processing using YCbCr color space. I am new at image processing field.I want to clear my concept about YCbCr. The question is How many bits-per-pixel are required to store the YCbCr images for S = 2, 4, 8 and 16?
 Help is needed. Kindly explain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the meaning of S?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same as for RGB. Multiply by 3: Y - Cb  - Cr.

YCbCr is simply a different way of representing color. It is similar to the method used in olde TV sets where you had a base grayscale signal with Tint and Hue added. YCbCR is the same with redness and blueness added to grayscale.